# HHVM Class Undefined SleepWaitHandle

Tags: php, laravel, hhvm, hacklang

I'm trying to use HHVM's async functions in a larval application. I added the async keyword to my function but I get an error on the line with await SleepWaitHandle. It says that the class is undefined. It doesn't seem like the documentation has changed on this. What am I missing?

```
await \SleepWaitHandle::create(\DB::table('submissions')->insert($submissions_for_insert));
```

I had this happen on a 3.9 nightly and 3.8 stable. Running ubuntu 14.10.

I tried running a demo from http://hhvm.com/blog/7091/async-cooperative-multitasking-for-hack

```
<?hh

async function hello(): Awaitable<string> {
  return "Hello World";
}
async function goodbye(): Awaitable<string> {
  return "Goodbye, everybody!";
}
async function run(
  array<Awaitable<string>> $handles,
): Awaitable<array<string>> {
  await AwaitAllWaitHandle::fromArray($handles);
  return array_map($handle ==> $handle->result(), $handles);
}
$results = run(array(hello(), goodbye()))->getWaitHandle()->join();
print_r($results);
// Array
// (
//  [0] => Hello World
//  [1] => Goodbye, everybody!
// )
```

But running this on the command line returns

```
Catchable fatal error: Hack type error: Invalid argument at /test/asyn.php line 12
```

Answer (score 1):

- To your first problem: `\SleepWaitHandle` in fact does not exist. The fully-qualified class name is `\HH\SleepWaitHandle` (or maybe `\HH\Asio\SleepWaitHandle`, I don't quite remember). If you notice, all the examples omit the leading `\` -- in Hack code, several classes, such as `SleepWaitHandle`, are automatically imported into your current namespace, provided there is no conflicting class name. You need to either use this behavior, or use the correct fully-qualified name.
- To your second problem, this is a bug in the example on the blog -- oops! The parameter to `run` should be `array<WaitHandle<string>> $handles`. I've updated the example in the blog post. It's a weird example though -- you normally don't work with `AwaitAllWaitHandle` directly; instead, you should be using the `\HH\Asio\v()` and `\HH\Asio\m()` functions, perhaps with support from the official [asio-utilities composer package](https://github.com/hhvm/asio-utilities).